# Sum all possible combinations of an array with python

Tags: python, math, sum, combinations, nested-loops

Have a good day. I have tried to find a real solution for the sum of all possible combinations of an array but have not found any so far using python.

Commonly people ask about the following combinatorics:

Given: a, b, c, d and e as records:

```
a+b
a+c
a+d
a+e
b+c
b+d
b+e
c+d
c+e
d+e
```

The real combination would be:

```
a+b
a+c
a+d
a+e
a+b+c
a+b+d
a+b+e
a+c+d
a+c+e
a+d+e
a+b+c+d
a+b+c+e
a+c+d+e
a+b+c+d+e
b+c
b+d
b+e
b+c+d
b+c+e
b+d+e
c+d
c+e
c+d+e
d+e
```

So, the result I need to obtain is the following, but so far I have not found how to iterate it to cover any size of the array:

```
| COMBINATION |      SUM     |
|-------------|--------------|
|a+b          |           XXX|
|a+c          |           XXX|
|a+d          |           XXX|
|a+e          |           XXX|
|a+b+c        |           XXX|
|a+b+d        |           XXX|
|a+b+e        |           XXX|
|a+c+d        |           XXX|
|a+c+e        |           XXX|
|a+d+e        |           XXX|
|a+b+c+d      |           XXX|
|a+b+c+e      |           XXX|
|a+c+d+e      |           XXX|
|a+b+c+d+e    |           XXX|
|b+c          |           XXX|
|b+d          |           XXX|
|b+e          |           XXX|
|b+c+d        |           XXX|
|b+c+e        |           XXX|
|b+d+e        |           XXX|
|c+d          |           XXX|
|c+e          |           XXX|
|c+d+e        |           XXX|
|d+e          |           XXX|
```

Note that the combination size is variable and must cover the total number of records in the array. Anyone have any ideas, possibly with the mathematical algorithm that is actually being applied here?

Answer (score 2):

```
# Look at all subsets from size 2 up to the whole thing
for size in range(2, len(records) + 1):
   # Iterate through all subsets of size "size"
   for subset in itertools.combinations(records, size):
       # subset will be a subset of the records. Feel free
       # to grab their sum and print them out however you want
```

---

Edited: Accidentally mistyped `combinations` as `combination`.  Sorry.

Comment: Nice use of `combinations`. Upvote+

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

a = [2, 6, 7]
df = pd.DataFrame(product([0, 1], repeat=len(a)), columns=a)
df['sum'] = df[a] @ a
print(df)
```

This gives:

```
   2  6  7  sum
0  0  0  0    0
1  0  0  1    7
2  0  1  0    6
3  0  1  1   13
4  1  0  0    2
5  1  0  1    9
6  1  1  0    8
7  1  1  1   15
```

The first three columns of the dataframe are labeled with elements of the list `a`. The value of 0 in a column indicates that the corresponding element of `a` is used in a sum, and `0` that it is not used. The last column gives sums of the elements of `a` selected in this way.

If you are interested only in sums that involve at least two elements of `a`, then you can select the relevant rows of the dataframe using `df[df[a].sum(axis=1) >= 2]`.

**Edit.** The code above produces a dataframe consisting of `2**len(a)` rows. For larger values of `len(a)` this will use a lot of memory. In such cases, it may be better to produce sums one by one in a loop instead of computing a dataframe with all of them. This can be done, for example, as follows:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

a = [2, 6, 7]
arr = np.array(a)
for p in product([0, 1], repeat=len(a)):
    print(p, p @ arr)
```

Comment: Excellent, this method worked well for me. The only problem is that my PC memory burst when I put in the 912 values ​​that are needed. The code for my problem looked like this (I'm looking for specific sum result of one of these combinations): a = [257142661.01,234320127.23,71825806.45,56500000.00,46907062.43,43565500.00,31957084.77,30000000.00,29154934.90,28020537.30]
df = pd.DataFrame(product([0, 1], repeat=len(a)), columns=a)
df['sum'] = df[a] @ a
df_filtrado =  df.loc[(df['sum']==46907062.43 )]
df_filtrado

Comment: @WescoT For longer lists it is better to produce sums in a loop, one by one, to avoid memory problems. This is particularly useful if you are looking for a specific sum, since you can break the loop when you find it. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Wooow, it works perfect!!! You're great buddy! Thank you so much!!